# telegram bot(using bot commands to pass variables in python code)

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

This is the code for my telegram bot that detects amazon.in links and returns the link with an amazon affiliate tag added to the link, I've hosted this bot on heroku and I've declared these environment variables(mentioned below in double quotes) in the config vars of the heroku app and it's working fine.

Now I want these variables to be passed to the bot using some command and then run the bot accordingly.
I want the environment variables like "TOKEN", "baseURL", "affiliate_tag" to passed using some bot commands to the telegram bot.

The code is in 'bot.py' file.

[This is the github repository link](https://github.com/khanyasar022/tgaffiliate-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the command (i.e. `/help a b`) which are made available in the `CommandHandler` as list in the `CallbackContext`

```
def help_command_handler(update, context):
"""Help handler"""
print(context.args)

baseURL = context.args[0]
affiliate_tag = context.args[1]
```